# programatically creating a folder in ssrs using SOAP

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the SSRS 2008r API to create and manage SSRS from a webform application. When creating a folder I see where I can add a folder name as well as specify additional meta data (custom properties) that can be a part of the folder. My question is how do I populate additional fields in the catalog database via the api. When I look at the CreateFolder method the only properties I can add at the insert are folder name, path, and custom properties:

```
rs.CreateFolder(folderName, "/", props); // foldername is a string passed in from the form
```

However I would also like to set at this time the description, and hidden value.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how this is accomplished. Every example I have seen within MSDN only shows setting the folder name, path, and custom properties.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [item properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152826.aspx) (`Description` and `Hidden`) by initializing a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.property%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) class for each. Never done it before, but I'm guessing it would look something like this (assuming C#):

```
...
// description property
Property description = new Property();
description.Name = "Description";
description.Value = "Your description here.";

// hidden property
Property hidden = new Property();
hidden.Name = "Hidden";
hidden.Value = "True"; // not sure on value here, may be True/False, Yes/No

// build properties array
props[0] = description;
props[1] = hidden;

// create folder
rs.CreateFolder(folderName, "/", props); // foldername is a string passed in from the form
```